# Native app install banner on chrome for iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, native

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android

Judging by the contents here, it seems that we can specify different native stores in the related_applications

What should the pattern be for chrome browsers installed in iOS? Is that something supported currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system is designed for future extension for other platforms to be able adopt it.  Right now we don't support this in iOS and we don't have a timeline or plans to support it in the near future.